# Camera preview is distorted

Tags: android, android-camera

I have some troubles with camera. I test my code on Xiaomi Mi2a and preview was distorted.
I have this line in manifest: `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`
I use camera with this fragment:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,       Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PreviewCallback, Camera.AutoFocusCallback,   View.OnClickListener {

private Camera mCamera;
private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
private SurfaceView mPreview;
private ImageButton mTakePicture;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false);

    mPreview = (SurfaceView) v.findViewById(R.id.svCameraView);

    mSurfaceHolder = mPreview.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    mTakePicture = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ibTakePicture);
    mTakePicture.setOnClickListener(takePictureOnClickListener);

    ImageButton switchCameraButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ibSwitchCamera);
    switchCameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

    return v;
}

View.OnClickListener takePictureOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
};


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mCamera = Camera.open();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

    List<String> flashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
    /*if (flashModes != null && flashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF))
        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);*/

    List<String> whiteBalance = parameters.getSupportedWhiteBalance();
    if (whiteBalance != null && whiteBalance.contains(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO))
        parameters.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);

    List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
    if (focusModes != null && focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO))
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);

    List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    /*if (sizes != null && sizes.size() > 0) {
        Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
        parameters.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
    }*/

    List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    /*if (previewSizes != null) {
        Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(previewSizes.size() - 1);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
    }*/

    Camera.Size previewSize = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    float aspect = (float) previewSize.width / previewSize.height;

    int previewSurfaceWidth = mPreview.getWidth();
    int previewSurfaceHeight = mPreview.getHeight();

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mPreview.getLayoutParams();

    if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        lp.height = previewSurfaceHeight;
        lp.width = (int) (previewSurfaceHeight / aspect);
    } else {
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
        lp.width = previewSurfaceWidth;
        lp.height = (int) (previewSurfaceWidth / aspect);
    }

    mPreview.setLayoutParams(lp);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    mCamera.startPreview();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == mTakePicture) {

        //mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, this);
        mCamera.autoFocus(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, Camera paramCamera) {
    paramCamera.startPreview();
}

@Override
public void onAutoFocus(boolean paramBoolean, Camera paramCamera) {
    if (paramBoolean) {
        paramCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, Camera paramCamera) {
}
```

I don't know how about resulting image, because I'm not need it at the moment. But preview is distorted. For example:

http://habrastorage.org/files/fc5/cd1/6fb/fc5cd16fb80f41f6ac7a8a800e0348b6.png
http://habrastorage.org/files/968/cd4/850/968cd48505564f93b0258a07fe48a545.png

What do I wrong? How to keep preview in normal state, without stretching? Or, maybe, is it problem with miui?

Comment: Have you checked whether the ratios(width/height) of Preview and SurfaceView are same?

Answer (score 0):

> How to keep preview in normal state, without stretching?

Your `SurfaceView` needs to be in the same aspect ratio as is the camera preview. Otherwise, the camera preview will be stretched in one direction to fit the `SurfaceView`.

Comment: Grafika now has some examples.  "Show + capture camera" and "Continuous capture" now use a custom layout to adjust the SurfaceView aspect ratio to match the camera.  "Texture from Camera" uses an entirely different approach.  https://github.com/google/grafika

Comment: It turns out that some Xiaomi devices give an invalid previewSize. For example, I have the MI3 and the camera says that supports preview size 640x480, but it does not. Instead, it takes a frame with a different size (and in my case different aspect ratio) and it's internally resizing it to 640x480. That's producing a distorted frame. It's a problem from Xiaomi for some given preview resolutions (specially low ones).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Take Video Size or Picture Size Available on Device
check in preview constructor-
    List<Camera.Size> sizes = mCamera.getParameters()
                    .getSupportedVideoSizes();
            if (sizes != null)
                for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {

                    int h = size.height;
                    int w = size.width;
                    System.out.println("h=" + h + " w=" + w);

                }
then decide what resolution you want for you requirment then make frame layout of same resoultion

abc.xml file
      <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
                    android:layout_width="288dp"
                    android:layout_height="352dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    >
            </FrameLayout>

preview in surface created-
if(mCamera!=null)
             {
             Parameters params=mCamera.getParameters();
             params.setPictureSize(288, 352);
             mCamera.setParameters(params);
             }

please make change according to your need if you need any help then ask.
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Camera Parameter as

Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

```
params.set("orientation", "portrait");
```

mCamera.setParameters(params);

this will help you..